# Stable-Diffusion webui-user.bat gets stuck after "Model loaded"

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

My local Stable-Diffusion installation was working fine. One day after starting webui-user.bat the command window got stuck after this:

```
venv "...\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Commit hash: 5ab7f213bec2f816f9c5644becb32eb72c8ffb89
Installing requirements
Launching Web UI with arguments:
No module 'xformers'. Proceeding without it.
Loading weights [cc6cb27103] from ...\StableDiffusion\models\Stable-diffusion\v1-5-pruned-emaonly.ckpt
Creating model from config: ...\StableDiffusion\configs\v1-inference.yaml
LatentDiffusion: Running in eps-prediction mode
DiffusionWrapper has 859.52 M params.
Applying cross attention optimization (Doggettx).
Textual inversion embeddings loaded(0):
Model loaded in 4.7s (load weights from disk: 2.2s, create model: 0.3s, apply weights to model: 0.4s, apply half(): 0.4s, move model to device: 0.4s, load textual inversion embeddings: 1.0s).
```

Nothing happens after this. Just doesn't continue (doesn't show the ip for the web interface).
I think I uninstalled/installed Python again before this happened. But not sure anymore.
I didn't change the webui-user.bat.

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved: after reinstalling python 3.10 again it works for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I have found a quickfix for now :
After Ctrl-C, python tells us where the program was interrupted by the SIGKILL signal :

`Model loaded in 2.5s (load weights from disk: 0.7s, create model: 0.3s, apply weights to model: 0.5s, apply half(): 0.4s, move model to device: 0.4s). ^CInterrupted with signal 2 in <frame at 0xafb7540, file '/home/geoffrey/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.py', line 260, code wait_on_server`

We can see that webui.py stopped its execution at line 260.
When looking at this line we can see this function :

```
def wait_on_server(demo=None):
    while(1):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if shared.state.need_restart:
            shared.state.need_restart = False
            time.sleep(0.5)
            demo.close()
            time.sleep(0.5)

            modules.script_callbacks.app_reload_callback()
            break
```

So the installation script is clearly stuck in this while 1 loop.
To fix this, I added a global boolean variable to the script to only restart the ui once at launch, and leave it alone all the next times :

```
launched = False

def wait_on_server(demo=None):
    global launched
    while(1):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if shared.state.need_restart or launched == False:
            shared.state.need_restart = False
            time.sleep(0.5)
            demo.close()
            time.sleep(0.5)

            modules.script_callbacks.app_reload_callback()
            launched = True
            break
```

I don't really know if this is going to cause some trouble later, but it looks like I can generate pictures by prompts (you just have to wait for the server to launch and connect at the address printed in the terminal) :D

Good luck guys !

Comment: Hi, Geoffrey!  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's preferred on this site to use code blocks instead of images when referencing sample code in your question or answer - see the discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors  I suggested an edit which formats your code samples in the recommended way, but this won't be visible until you or someone else approves it.

Answer (score 0):

Pay close attention to the messages that webui.bat throws out while it is running.  If there are error messages and a suggestion about how to fix the error, follow the directions and run webui.bat again.
Zaffer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).